# google cloud storage performance characteristics (latency / request response time)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm considering building an app on App Engine, and I'm trying to decide if I should  store  data in the datastore or on google cloud storage.

Each object is going to be typically no more than around a kilobyte, perhaps a few kilobytes  at most (and often less). It won't change too often.

I could have the client directly access the data, but though I might live without there would be some benefit to the app engine app accessing the data and using it as part of serving a response.

What are the performance characteristics of google cloud storage? How quickly do requests come back? I was able to find a status dashboard for the datastore which indicates that they are usually reasonably quick at handling requests but I've had trouble getting guidance on how fast GCS is.

Under the most recent price reductions, it seems like the datastore might actually be cheaper for my use case of relatively small chunks of data ($0.06/100,000 requests vs $0.01/10,000 class b operations).  Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: This is quickly turning into an unanswerable close candidate, but you can prevent that by providing your use case and what kind of performance you are expecting. "Fast" is relative.

Comment: I agree 'fast' is relative, which is why I'm looking for numbers. Can I expect 99% of requests to return in 10ms? 25ms? 50ms? With the datastore I have their status dashboard which gives me a bit of an idea, with GCS I'm having trouble finding any data.

Comment: Instead of looking at it like that, why not try it the other way around. Your application needs response time of _x_ ms for data type of _y_. To _guarantee_ this response time; is _z_ appropriate or shall I use _p_? This is a question that can get a better answer, if you also preface it with some expected workload.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/5) might give you some insights. Back in september 2013 I had about 200-250ms on average for "blank" sequential inserts. You can get a great speedup if you combine your requests. You can insert up to 500 entities in a single request. Which takes roughly 500ms-900ms if I remember correctly.

Comment: However, the maximum request size is 10 mb.